# Can a C# application be accessed from an android mobile?

Tags: c#, android, ios, sql-server

​I have been developing custom applications in C# and SQL Server. I have a new requirement where the customer wants to be able to access their application from their android or apple mobile phone too.

I need to know whether a desktop application developed in C# and SQL Server would have this feature or if any components can be plugged-in to enable that feature? Or if not, what would it take to achieve this.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction and I'll figure out the rest.

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to write the android application too. You can write Android application using C# with Xamarin.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to run Windows programs on Android. A quick Google seemed to indicate that you can do some sort of remote desktop access from Android to a Windows machine and that might work. But then you'd need a running Windows machine to remote to.

Comment: @hendryanw if you are one of the lucky fews where xamarin can be installed. They really should fix the installer for this product

Comment: Hello Hans Kilian - accessing it through remote desktop is not what I am looking for. But thank you for your response. @Asdamp's response has answered by query for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio gives you the ability to build Native Android and iOS app using xamarin. It can solve your problem but it really depends on your software.
SQL, however, is unsupported by Android and iOS, if the database needs to reside on the device, you need to use another db, like SQLite for Android. 
If the database can be a remote db, you can build an API (REST?) and access to it using this API

[Native Android and iOS development with VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/visualstudio/cross-platform/build-apps-with-native-ui-using-xamarin-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Thanks, solved for now. The database will have to be a remote db as it should change each time the employee logs in. Can I know what did you mean by (REST?)

Comment: I was simply suggesting to implement an API using REST Services. This is usually my approach. Do not connect directly to a remote db using a connection string because this seriously undermines the security of your db